# How to simplify logarithm of exponent in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

When I type

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
sp.simplify(sp.log(sp.exp(x)))
```

I obtain

```
log(e^x)
```

Instead of `x`. I know that "there are no guarantees" on this function.

> **Question.** Is there some specific simplification (through series expansion or whatsoever) to convert logarithm of exponent into identity function?

Comment: [`sympy.expand_log(..., force=True)`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#expand-log) seems to work.

Comment: I think the accepted version is better because it gives a better understanding: instead of ignoring assumptions it is better to explicitly state them. It is useful to have a "force" version however. Your receipt also works if I do `expand_log` as a simplification at the end of computation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set `x` to real type and your code will work:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x', real=True)
print(sp.simplify(sp.log(sp.exp(x))))
```

Output: `x`.

For complex `x` result of this formula is not always is equal to `x`. Example is [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#exponentials-and-logarithms).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to force the simplification, `expand` can help because it offers the `force` keyword which basically makes certain assumptions like this for you without you having to declare your variables as real. But be careful with the result -- you will not want to use it when those assumptions are not warranted.

```
>>> log(exp(x)).expand(force=True)
x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the argument "inverse" to "True" in the simplify function:

```
>>> simplify(log(exp(x)), inverse=True)
x
```

Comment: This is a nice note: `inverse` will decompose `func(invfunc(x))` as `x`.