# How to use expand_log on matrix elements?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to simplify a sympy expression where the arguments are matrix elements using the function expand_log. 
As a simple example let's look at the expression log(exp(x)), which should be simplified to x.

As [the tutorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#exponentials-and-logarithms) explains, simplifications will  only be applied if the required assumptions hold, i.e. in this case, x must be real.

If I have a scalar quantity, I can specify this assumption when creating the variable as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129447/10201982).

However, I use a matrix symbol which does not allow specifying assumptions at creation. I instead tried using the new assumptions module:

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q

x = sym.MatrixSymbol('x',1,2)
expr = sym.log(sym.exp(x[0,0]))
with assuming(Q.real(x[0,0])):
    display(sym.expand_log(expr))
```

The output still is `log(exp(x[0, 0]))`.
So it seems to me that the `expand_log` function is not aware of the assumption that I specify in the assuming context manager.

Setting `force=True` yields the desired result but I want to avoid not checking assumptions at all.

Does anyone have an idea how to circumvent this problem?